# Get the current logging verbosity level in my MSBuild script

Tags: msbuild

Our MSBuild scripts use the Exec task to call a few command line applications.  Most of these applications have their own output verbosity settings which I would like to have be the same as the verbosity level of the MSBuild script calling them.

Is there a way for me to get the logging verbosity level of my MSBuild process?

I thought I could write a custom task to handle this, but poking around the MSBuild API, I couldn't find any properties or classes that would give me the verbosity level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Shortly after asking my questions, I noticed that **MSBuild 4** exposes `System.Environment.CommandLine` as a property function, which should include any verbosity arguments.  With the following bit of parsing, you can create several boolean properties that will tell you the current logging level:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CommandLine>$([System.Environment]::CommandLine.Trim().ToLower())</CommandLine>
  <IsQuietVerbosity>False</IsQuietVerbosity>
  <IsMinimalVerbosity>False</IsMinimalVerbosity>
  <IsNormalVerbosity>True</IsNormalVerbosity>
  <IsDetailedVerbosity>False</IsDetailedVerbosity>
  <IsDiagnosticVerbosity>False</IsDiagnosticVerbosity>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(CommandLine.Contains(&quot;/v&quot;))' == 'True'">
  <IndexOfLastVerbosityArg>$(CommandLine.LastIndexOf("/v"))</IndexOfLastVerbosityArg>
  <IndexOfVerbosityArg>$(CommandLine.IndexOf(":", $(IndexOfLastVerbosityArg)))</IndexOfVerbosityArg>
  <IndexOfVerbosityArg>$([MSBuild]::Add($(IndexOfVerbosityArg), 1))</IndexOfVerbosityArg>
  <IndexOfEndOfVerbosityArg>$(CommandLine.IndexOf(" ", $(IndexOfVerbosityArg)))</IndexOfEndOfVerbosityArg>
  <IndexOfEndOfVerbosityArg Condition="'$(IndexOfEndOfVerbosityArg)' == '-1'">$(CommandLine.Length)</IndexOfEndOfVerbosityArg>
  <LengthOfVerbosityArg>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(IndexOfEndOfVerbosityArg), $(IndexOfVerbosityArg)))</LengthOfVerbosityArg>
  <VerbosityLevel>$(CommandLine.Substring($(IndexOfVerbosityArg), $(LengthOfVerbosityArg)).Trim())</VerbosityLevel>
  <IsQuietVerbosity>$(VerbosityLevel.StartsWith('q'))</IsQuietVerbosity>
  <IsMinimalVerbosity>$(VerbosityLevel.StartsWith('m'))</IsMinimalVerbosity>
  <IsNormalVerbosity>$(VerbosityLevel.StartsWith('n'))</IsNormalVerbosity>
  <IsDiagnosticVerbosity>$(VerbosityLevel.StartsWith('di'))</IsDiagnosticVerbosity>
  <IsDetailedVerbosity Condition="'$(IsDiagnosticVerbosity)' == 'False'">$(VerbosityLevel.StartsWith('d'))</IsDetailedVerbosity>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

***Remember, this will only work in MSBuild 4+.***

Ugly?  Yup.  Kludgy?  Maybe.  Does it work.  Yup!

Comment: This doesn't work from the Visual Studio IDE, since msbuild appears to query information from the IDE using inter-process communication rather than something as mundane and reliable as a command line parameter.

Comment: Note that this [fails](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/pull/1020) with `dotnet build` and `dotnet msbuild`, don't know why.

Comment: I think you can check whether it will work by checking the [`MSBuildRuntimeType` reserved property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 2):

You can't : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/510f07b4-c5f7-43a8-b7cb-e3c398841725/

Instead, you can set a property of yours (passing it with the command line for example) which contains the verbosity level.